# Loopcut won't go through

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

Hi I'm a new at Blender can anyone help me?

I'm practicing to create an anime character, I clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to make a line to connect on the hand (as picture) but doesn't work, it doesn't go through on the back.

Does anyone know what should I do ? Please help me

I am sorry for my English

[image]

Comment: see if there are double vertices: select all vertices by pressing A , press W and use *remove doubles*

Comment: Also loop cuts will only go through connected quads (4 sided faces) there seems to be a gap on the bottom of your mesh (no pun intended)

Comment: It can be a combination of both, as @DuarteFarrajotaRamos pointed out, loops don't work on n-gons or tris, but it definitely appears there are some artifacts caused by doubles higher in the collarbone area of the neck.