# Can't use loop cut on some faces

Tags: modeling

I can't describe it with words, so I recorded video.

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdLqxZ5s9Bo&feature=youtu.be)

And I can't even cut them separately.

Can anyone help with it?

[image]

Comment: Only thing that i can think of is that there has to be double vertex or something similar. If the model is absolutely the same, it would be a bug. Just try select all vertexes and merge by distance, if there will be some merging there were more vertexes in one.

Comment: double vertex or face inside or separated faces?

Comment: There wasn't any double vertex. I tried merge all vertexes by distance and it says me "Removed 0 vertices".

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: ok I uploaded it. link in the post now

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57150 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870

Answer (score 0):

So as I said you have inner faces, but there are hidden so you need to unhide and delete. You can't create edge loops if the edge separates more than 2 faces, and by the way those inner faces are not good for your topology, it may create artifacts.

[image]

Comment: thanls a lot for help, i will try to delete them.